# Calling new activity after facebook login | Android

Tags: android, facebook

I have 2 activities in my android application. On the first one, I ask the user to login with facebook. after the user logs in, i collect the user data such as email, name and call a new activity passing these parameters to it. below is my facebook authorize method:

```
 public void loginFB(final View v)
    {           
        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "read_stream" }, new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                this.getlogininfo(v);
            }
            private void getlogininfo(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                logininfo(v);                   
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
     });            
    }
```

Below is my `logininfo()`  method:

```
public void logininfo(final View v){
    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener(){    
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            try{
                Log.d("Profile", response.toString());
                JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                final String fname1 = json.getString("first_name");
                final String lname1 = json.getString("last_name");
                final String email = json.getString("email");

                Intent fbLogged = new Intent();
                Bundle passData = new Bundle();
                passData.putString("fname", fname1);
                passData.putString("lname", lname1);
                passData.putString("email", email);
                fbLogged.putExtras(passData);
                fbLogged.setClass(v.getContext(), RequestFb.class);
                startActivity(fbLogged);    
            }
            catch(JSONException e){
                Log.w("This", "eror");
            }               
        }    
        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }           
    });
  }
```

So, my new activity  is starting on `OnComplete()` of getting the user data.

This works perfectly, but when the user clicks login, and logs in with facebook, the first activity page remains on the screen for a few seconds and then the next activity is called. there is a lag. How can I fix the lag? When the user clicks login and after the login is authorized, it should take the user to directly the second activity. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, you are running the fb graph request in a new thread (using the *AsyncRunner*) but only when that request is completed you start the new activity and that's why you get that "lag".

You should run the graph request in the new activity instead of the first one, something like:

```
public void loginFB(final View v) {
    facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "read_stream" }, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            Intent fbLogged = new Intent(v.getContext(), RequestFb.class);
            startActivity(fbLogged);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}

public class RequestFb extend Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Facebook facebook = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID");
        AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

        asyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener(){
            try {
                final JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                final String fname1 = json.getString("first_name");
                final String lname1 = json.getString("last_name");
                final String email = json.getString("email");

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // use the data
                    }
                });
            }
            catch(JSONException e) {
                Log.w("This", "eror");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. The problem is solved. I call the graph request in the new activity. Thank you.