# App created using Facebook-Android-SDK - redirecting user back to landing page after getting permissions

Tags: android, android-intent, facebook-android-sdk

I am extremely new to Android, infact Java as a whole - I am from a PHP background which is creating a challenge for me to work on Android.

My first task in Android is to implement Facebook session management using Facebook SDK in an existing App. I have started by importing the requisite SDK files and in the Landing screen of my App (Main Activity) I have written code as follows:

**onCreate()** -

- Creating FB object, storing it in Utility
- Instantiating the asynrunner object for asynchronous api calls and giving FB object        instance to AsyncronusRunner
- Restoring session if one exists by calling SessionStore.restore(),    *
- Calling init() like so-

  ```
  init(LandingPage.this, AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE, Utility.mFacebook, permissions);

  public void init(final Activity activity, final int activityCode, final Facebook fb, final String[] permissions) {
      mActivity = activity;
      mActivityCode = activityCode;
      mFb = fb;
      mPermissions = permissions;
      mHandler = new Handler();

      SessionEvents.addAuthListener(mSessionListener);
      SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(mSessionListener);      

  }// init()
  ```

**onStart()** -

- I have created a custom FB login button and I am type casting it to
  "Button" (not "LoginButton")
- On the onClick() of this "Button" object am checking if FB session is
  valid. If yes? get data from FB, proceed. If no? force user to see
  the Login Dialog Box for FB.

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fb_login);
      mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {

               if (Utility.mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
                  requestUserData();
               }else{
                   Utility.mFacebook.authorize.authorize(mActivity, mPermissions, mActivityCode, new LoginDialogListener());
               }
          }
      });
  }//onStart()


  private class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

      public void onComplete(Bundle values) {             

          SessionEvents.onLoginSuccess();
          requestUserData(); //userData fetches FB profile data

      }// onComplete() 
  }// class
  ```

**requestUserData()** -

- Here I have simply created a Bundle to pass the fields that I need:

  ```
  public void requestUserData() {     

      Bundle params = new Bundle();
      params.putString("fields", "first_name, name, id, picture, gender, email");
      Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me", params, new UserRequestListener()); // callback for fetching fields          

  }// requestUserData()


  public class UserRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {  

      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
      @Override
      public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {     

          JSONObject jsonObject;
          try {
              jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
              final String picURL = jsonObject.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
              final String first_name = jsonObject.getString("first_name");
              final String full_name  = jsonObject.getString("name");
              final String gender = jsonObject.getString("gender");
              final String fb_id  = jsonObject.getString("id");
              String email        = "" ; // initialized blank first otherwise gives Json exception if email returned null from FB

              // store values in Singleton
              Singleton.fb_firstname  = first_name ; //although it says "first name", am storing full name in there
              Singleton.fb_user_id    = fb_id;                    
              Singleton.fb_gender = gender;               
              try {
                  email   = jsonObject.getString("email");//sometimes we dont get an email from Facebook
                  Singleton.fb_email_id   = email;

              } catch (JSONException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }   

              Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
              String mAccessToken = access_token;
              parameters.putString("format", "json");
              parameters.putString(TOKEN, mAccessToken);  

              String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends";
              String friends_response = null;

              try {
                  friends_response = Util.openUrl(url, "GET", parameters);
              } catch (Exception e1) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e1.printStackTrace();
              }
              JSONObject obj = Util.parseJson(friends_response);

              ..........
              // CALLING A WEBSERVICE THAT RETURNS A USER-ID BASED ON THE FACEBOOK ID     
              // If the service returns status=0, we need to redirect user to Screen A, else to ScreenB
              ..........
              if(status.equals("0")){                     

                  Intent intent = new Intent(LandingPage.this,ScreenA.class);
                  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                  startActivity(intent);
                  finish();

              }else {         
                  Intent intent = new Intent(LandingPage.this, ScreenB.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
                  finish();
              }//else             

          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

      ]// onComplete()
   }// class()
  ```

Now my issue lies in requestUserData()

Once I have all the Facebook profile data that I need for processing, I execute an if/else condition that is supposed to process the variables returned in FB call response and based on that redirect the user to ScreenA or ScreenB immediately, that is in this sequence:

> **1.** User launches App, comes to "LandingPage" where MainActivity
>   starts 
>       **2.** User clicks on "FB Connect" button on "LandingPage" 
>       **3.** OnClick() event of the button fires invoking an instance of LoginDialogListener() 
>       **4.** LoginDialogListener takes user to the FB login screen asking for username/password - user enters credentials and also
>   authorizes the App successfully via the permission screens 
>       **5.** Once he clicks "Ok" on the final permission screen, the user is brought BACK to the "LandingPage" for a few seconds and then
>   redirected to "ScreenA" or "ScreenB" as given in the if/else block
>   given above.

Basically what I need is for the user to NOT be thrown back to the "LandingPage" and directly be sent to the respective screen as per my logic. But this doesn't seem to happen, no matter what I tried. For a fraction of a second the user always comes back to the LandingPage after authorizing the app and then is sent to the next screen. How can I avoid this?

Note: In my Native Android Facebook settings, I have given class name as: LandingPage. So I guess after authorization is completed, the user gets re-directed back to the LandingPage for a fraction of a second (but none of the methods such as create, start, init get called again) before getting redirected to ScreenA/ScreenB - I am really clueless here.

What I would ideally want is, if its not possible to direct a user to another screen halfway when the previous screen logic is still under processing, maybe can I sort of block the user from atleast seeing the landing page view again (which might make him think there was something wrong with the App) and instead show him an alert like "Processing..." or something replacing the current view of the landing page until he gets successfully redirected to ScreenA/ScreenB?

If anyone can guide me here, I would really appreciate it.

Regards,
Mahek

Comment: Got a good lead - this thread here seems helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885360/calling-new-activity-after-facebook-login-android
Will be trying it now.

Comment: The code you're using (and the one you're linking above) are all using now deprecated classes in the SDK. If you're starting a new project, please use the new Session classes. See the getting started guide (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/) and the SDK tutorial (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/)